# Disable TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 using httpd

Tags: centos, ssl, centos7, httpd

I am moving from `Debian` to `CentOS 7`.
I used the same `Apache/httpd` arguments in my `.config` files.

Somehow `TLSv1.0` and `TLS1.1`seems to be enabled in `httpd`.

I tested my active `TLS` versions using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jonas-heinze.de&hideResults=on and https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test

Under `Debian` I used `SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2` to disable it.

If I add `-TLSv1` and `-TLSv1.1` it is still enabled.

Do I need a different configuration in `httpd`?

Comment: Are you using the Apache 2.4.6 from default repository?

Comment: In what file would this configuration setting be made and or found in and does this vary in file names between OS? I'm on centos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` like this:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

Comment: It won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update your **openssl** and **httpd** packages. The correct syntax for apache2.4 should be

> SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

You also must restart the httpd daemon after updating and changing configuration. I would recommend using https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ to generate your SSL Configuration and adapt it to your needs.

Please also make sure there is no reverse proxy in front of your server. In case there is you should change the corresponding setting on the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix issue.
First I tried to update my apache server, which seems to be up to date (Apache 2.4.6).
Then I tried the config suggested by @igrek51 and tested the available TLS versions. Somehow it worked this time.

Thanks for all your suggestions and effort you put into this question.

Have a nice day

MrWaffelXD

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and after research, make sure that the configuration on the virtual servers explicitly use:

> SSLEngine on

> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

because using it only on the ssl.conf is not enough